# Shared library for the DSL scripts

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

How can i use shared library in jenkins for my dsl groovy scripts?

Most of my scripts have same steps except few changes in name and url, i do not want to create new script every time. Is there any way one script and do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a [Jenkins shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and configure it in Jenkins.

The shared library is a git repository with defined structure where you declare your shared steps and you can include it in each pipeline script with `@Library('<library name>')`.